# How to set column width in excel sheet while downloading the data in CSV format?

Tags: tabulator

I'm using Tabulator framework for my UI table. I need to download the data as CSV file. I'm using the following coe to download.

```
table.download("CSV", "filename.csv");
```

It's creating the CSV file properly, but when I open it with excel sheet, the column widths are not set properly and looking like below.[downloaded CSV file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Zg66.png)

How to set the column width so that the values in the cells doesn't look wierd?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can't format a CSV file.

You have to use a file format which supports column widths, such as xls, xlsx.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. But, in Tabulator framework, how can we set the column width?